# python annotate function that passes parameters to another function

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

```
def foo(myarg, **other_args):
    # do something
    return bar(**other_args)
```

Is it possible to annotate this function in a way that would make it clear to IDEs that `other_args` are the arguments of function `bar()`? So that the IDE would provide a helpful code completion in this case.